# i can do http://pc_name and smb://pc_name... to test my local site or use shared resources. anything similar that is so handy?

Tags: apache, url, testing, smb

when testing out our machine for apache or SVN, i found that we can actually use

http://pc_name

when our computer is named "pc_name" and other PC on the same network can access that PC by that URL at port 80.

and a mac can connect to my PC shared resources by Finder -> Connect to Server -> smb://pc_name

these are great.  are there similar things that are great but i just haven't found out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pc_name works only, if a DNS server in the network is active that has assigned the name to the pc named "pc_name" or if the "hosts" file is modificated.

Maybe there are a lot things you haven't found out. Your question isn't specific enough for a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

[SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)?

As Martin says: Your question isn't specific enough.

Comment: Did anyone actually see the SSH-link? :/